# changing schema at run time delphi 5/ crystal 8.5

Tags: oracle, delphi, crystal-reports-8.5

Ive got a database right now with one username that the front (delphi 5) end connects to. 
we call reports using the following:

```
with tcrpe.create(self) do
    try
      report_name := 'CrystalLotRecapSummary.rpt';
      if fileexists(dmposting.tws_drive+'\tws\special\'+report_name) then
        ReportName := dmposting.tws_drive+'\tws\special\'+Report_Name
      else
        ReportName := dmposting.tws_drive+'\tws\reports\harvest\'+Report_Name;
      WindowButtonBar.PrintSetupBtn := true;
      Paramfields.retrieve;
      ParamFields[0].Value := cmbCropYear.text;  // IN OLD REPORT
      ParamFields[1].Value := 'ALL';
      ParamFields[2].Value := real_to_str(unitfactor,0);  // IN OLD REPORT
      ParamFields[3].Value := cmbUnit.text; // IN OLD REPORT
      ConnectMethod := useConnect;
      Connect.Retrieve;
      Connect.Password := 'PASSWORD';
      Output := toWindow;
      Execute;
    finally
      CloseJob;
    end;
end; // PRINT SUMMARY BY WAREHOUSE
```

This works just fine. the problem is that we are now about to have 2 schemas (sysdba and sysdba2).

right now the crystal reports query looks like:

```
SELECT
LOT_RECAP."GROWING_YEAR", LOT_RECAP."GREEN", LOT_RECAP."ADJUSTED", LOT_RECAP."SHIPPED",
LOT_RECAP."WAREHOUSE_ID", LOT_RECAP."REMAINING", LOT_RECAP."LOT_ID",
LOT_RECAP."FINISH_DRYING", LOT_RECAP."NAME", LOT_RECAP."STATUS",
LOT_RECAP."COMMODITY_ID",
LOT_RECAP."VARIETY_ID", LOT_RECAP."PRODUCER_ID", LOT_RECAP."LR_AVMOISTURE",
LOT_RECAP."PROJECTED", LOT_RECAP."NOTE", LOT_RECAP."MASTER_ID",
LOT_RECAP."VARIETY_TYPE",
LOT_RECAP."CROP", LOT_RECAP."STORAGE_ONLY"
FROM
"SYSDBA"."LOT_RECAP" LOT_RECAP
WHERE
LOT_RECAP."GROWING_YEAR" = 2009 AND
LOT_RECAP."COMMODITY_ID" = 'RICE' AND
LOT_RECAP."STORAGE_ONLY" = 'FALSE'
ORDER BY
LOT_RECAP."LOT_ID" ASC
```

I need to figure out some way to have the report to decide if the userid is sysdba then the table is sysdba.lot_recap, and if the userid is sysdba2 then the table name is sysdba2.lot_recap. BTW, Ive got to do this for about 300 reports. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If i didnt provide enough info please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok issue was finally figured out. By going into the report itself and then going to Set Location. If i remove the schema name from the location Crystal reports will let me assign the schema name dynamically based on the username i sign in with.

Answer (score 0):

See the [ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT SCHEMA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general009.htm) command.

Answer (score 0):

create a view to union both tables and select by a new column "userid":

```
create view LOT_RECAP_ALL as
 select 'sysdba' userid, l.* from sysdba.lot_recap l
 union all
 select 'sysdba2' userid, l.* from sysdba2.lot_recap l
;
```

And now modify your select to select from LOT_RECAP_ALL and add LOT_RECAP."USERID" = 'sysdba' (or sysdba2):

```
SELECT
LOT_RECAP."GROWING_YEAR", LOT_RECAP."GREEN", LOT_RECAP."ADJUSTED", LOT_RECAP."SHIPPED",
LOT_RECAP."WAREHOUSE_ID", LOT_RECAP."REMAINING", LOT_RECAP."LOT_ID",
LOT_RECAP."FINISH_DRYING", LOT_RECAP."NAME", LOT_RECAP."STATUS",
LOT_RECAP."COMMODITY_ID",
LOT_RECAP."VARIETY_ID", LOT_RECAP."PRODUCER_ID", LOT_RECAP."LR_AVMOISTURE",
LOT_RECAP."PROJECTED", LOT_RECAP."NOTE", LOT_RECAP."MASTER_ID",
LOT_RECAP."VARIETY_TYPE",
LOT_RECAP."CROP", LOT_RECAP."STORAGE_ONLY"
FROM
"LOT_RECAP_ALL" LOT_RECAP
WHERE
LOT_RECAP."GROWING_YEAR" = 2009 AND
LOT_RECAP."COMMODITY_ID" = 'RICE' AND
LOT_RECAP."STORAGE_ONLY" = 'FALSE' AND
LOT_RECAP."USERID" = 'sysdba' -- or sysdba2
ORDER BY
LOT_RECAP."LOT_ID" ASC
```

Depending on your connecting user you might need to add

```
grant select on LOT_RECAP_ALL to sysdba;
```

or

```
grant select on LOT_RECAP_ALL to sysdba2;
```

And maybe you also need to add select grants on sysdba(2).lot_recap to the view owner. Can't tell this from here, depends on your schemas' access privileges.

Comment: theres a sysdba.lot_recap_all, and a sysdba2.lot_recap all. when the user looks at the report with the login as sysdba i want them to see the report populated with data frm sysdba.lot_recap_all, and if they log in as sysdba2 i want them to see the report with data populated with data from sysda2.lot_recap_all. The only way i've found so far is to go in and create 2 different reports, and thats what im trying to avoid. If i do that i have to go in and edit all 300 reports manually, and then i have to go manually insert a statement to redesign where the report points to based on the login,

Comment: because the select statement that i showed you looks for the fully quakified table, theres not a way to look at just 'LOT_RECAP_ALL' i dont want sydba to have access to sysdba2 and vice versa, i want to force crystal to pull from either sysdba or sysdba2 based on my logins with out having to go in and do them manually

Comment: Well, the simplest solution would be to remove the schema qualifier from the select. 

If you can't change the select statement with the fully qualified table, I see no way to trick oracle into using a different table.

Is LOT_RECAP a view or a table? If it's a view, you can still use my approach: rename it, use my view which selects from the renamed originals, do the grants and query with userid=USER.

Or there is some way in crystal, but that I don't know of.

Comment: its a table, and the select statement has to be qualified inside crystal reports, and if it was just one i would probably do this, but its several hundred reports. It looks like the real solution is just going to be to drop crystal reports. We've been looking for an excuse to and am probably going to just go to Fast reports because it looks like there it doesnt have to be fully qualified, either way im going to spend a couble hundered hours making changes (yay...)